# Using CNN to get value from dartboard where dart landed

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, conv-neural-network

I want to use CNN in python to get values from dartboard (or the value of the field where dart landed) using pictures.

I took 208 photos of dartboard, in each dart is in specific location. I want to predict if the dart in next image is in specific field (208 pictures represent 4 classes/52 each) (single, double and triple from same field represent same number or in our case, same class.

[sample dart in a field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqzb.png)

Then i use similar picture to test model.

When I try to fit model I get something like this

```
208/208 [==============================] - 3s 15ms/sample - loss: 0.0010 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 8.1726 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 29/100
208/208 [==============================] - 3s 15ms/sample - loss: 9.8222e-04 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 8.6713 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 30/100
208/208 [==============================] - 3s 15ms/sample - loss: 8.5902e-04 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 9.2214 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
Epoch 31/100
208/208 [==============================] - 3s 15ms/sample - loss: 7.9463e-04 - accuracy: 1.0000 - val_loss: 9.6584 - val_accuracy: 0.2500
```

As the accuracy hits 1 the val_accuracy stays the same, some previous model got me a little better result, but it was little better than this.

As I am new in the field I need some advice to get my model or whole program better.

Here is my current model_

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(640, 480, 3)))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))

model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))

model.add(Conv2D(256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(2, 2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))

model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(X, y, batch_size=16, epochs=100, validation_data=(Xtest,ytest))
```

AND MY SAMPLE PROGRAM

```
training_data = []
DATADIR = 'C:/PikadaNew'

dir = sorted(os.listdir(DATADIR), key=len)
def create_training_data():
    for category in dir:  # do dogs and cats
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category)
        class_num = dir.index(category) 
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)): 
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))     
                training_data.append([img_array, class_num])      
            except Exception as e: 
                pass          

create_training_data()

DATATESTDIR = 'C:/PikadaNewTest'
dir1 = sorted(os.listdir(DATATESTDIR), key=len)
test_data = []

def create_test_data():
    for category in dir1:
        path = os.path.join(DATATESTDIR,category) 
        class_num = dir1.index(category) 
        for img in tqdm(os.listdir(path)):
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))  # convert to array
                test_data.append([img_array, class_num])                
            except Exception as e:
                pass

create_test_data()

#print(len(training_data))
#print(len(test_data))

X = []
y = []

Xtest = []
ytest = []

for features,label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    y.append(label)

for features,label in test_data:
    Xtest.append(features)
    ytest.append(label)


X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, 640, 480, 3)
Xtest= np.array(Xtest).reshape(-1, 640, 480, 3)
y = np.array(y)
ytest = np.array(ytest)


y = to_categorical(y)
ytest = to_categorical(ytest)


X = X/255.0
Xtest = Xtest/255.0


X,y = shuffle(X,y)
Xtest,ytest = shuffle(Xtest,ytest)
```

Thanks and sorry for mistakes, i hope its understandable what i wanna to achieve
Every advice is much appreciated
Samo

Answer (score 0):

You are facing an overfitting problem because your data are so small and the model in more complex than needed. you can try the following:

- Add more data if you can.
- Try to simplify the model by removing some layers.
- Add dropout to the model and use regularizes.
- Use smaller number of epochs.

Comment: I cant add more data, this is the max number of pictures per field, i want show how accuracy falls as less pictures are imported to the model. Simplifying model didnt give any good results. You have any idea where to put dropouts and where to properly use regularizes? Using smaller number of epochs doesnt show us how model is doing in later stages? I would use smaller number if results where better